# Read multiple tables from xlsx using apache poi in java

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx, excel-tables

I am able to read rows and columns in xlsx using this [link](https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-excel-file-apache-poi/) for one table using Apache POI from java.

**How to read data from multiple tables from the same xlsx sheet in java using Apache POI?**

[image]

In the above image, there are two tables.
**How to distinguish and read the shown separate tables in the same xlsx sheet using Apache POI from Java?**

I have tried this code -

```
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new File("test.xlsx"));
    int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
    for(int sheetIdx = 0; sheetIdx < numberOfSheets; sheetIdx++) {
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetIdx);
    List<XSSFTable> tables = sheet.getTables();
    for(XSSFTable t : tables) {
        System.out.println(t.getDisplayName());
        System.out.println(t.getName());
        System.out.println(t.getNumerOfMappedColumns());
    }
}
```

But, the above code did not work in my case.
Can anyone help me regarding this?I have a deadline to my work.

Any other ideas on how to arrange multiple tables in the same spreadsheet and read them using java & apache poi?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think, that `XSSFTable` represents special entities - like tables created via Insert -> Table in Excel. Screenshots shows there are no such objects, just a set of filled cells with values. So you have to read them like `sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j)` and check if cell is empty.

Comment: Thank you for the response! The above code worked with Insert -> Table in Excel, as suggested.